# What's the meaning of "Artist's rendering "?

Tags: word-meaning

I saw this [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20190707031803/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sls_block1_on-pad_sunrisesmall.jpg),

> **Artist's rendering** of the Space Launch System Block 1 sitting on
>   Launch Pad 39A with the Orion spacecraft at sunrise.

I am confused with the word "Artist's rendering ". Does it mean Artist draw the picture?

Picture more look like a camera product than a painting product.

Comment: This is probably a 3D CGI render of this scene, created from a number of photographic references.  Some artists, myself included, would object to calling it an "artist's rendering" as this normally implies it is a hand drawn (digital) image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expression used to say that this is a drawing (or painting etc) and not a photograph. In this case, it is "photorealistic digital art", the artist has created a picture that looks like a photograph, but it is not. Look carefully at the image, you will see, for example, that the plants in the background are all the same.